# jquery : add option value in array object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i using jquery datatables , i have 2x table with aoColumns option and 1x without aoColumns

so i want do the following

```
if(aoColumns != false)
add option in array
```

i tried that but it didnt work

```
function Data_Table_Function(file,Language,ServerParams,Row_Call_Back,pagation,columns_sort,aoColumnDefs){
var  Options_Data_Table = {};

Options_Data_Table = {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": file,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bPaginate": true,
        "oLanguage": Language,
         "iDisplayLength": 25,
         "aLengthMenu": [
            [10, 25, 50, 100, -1],
            [10, 25, 50, 100, "الكل"]
        ],
        "fnServerParams": ServerParams,
        "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        "fnRowCallback": Row_Call_Back,
        "fnDrawCallback": pagation,
        "bInfo": false,
        "aoColumnDefs":aoColumnDefs
    };

    if(columns_sort)
    Options_Data_Table.push("aoColumns" : columns_sort);    


return  Options_Data_Table;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Options_Data_Table` is object, not array:

```
Options_Data_Table["aoColumns"] = columns_sort;
```

OR

```
Options_Data_Table.aoColumns = columns_sort;
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `push` when it comes to objects (as it is a method exclusive to arrays).

Use:

```
Options_Data_Table.aoColumns = columns_sort;
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that **Options_Data_Table** is an object, not an array. In javascript arrays are declared with: [ ]

Documentation about javascript arrays:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp

The correct way for add that property is:

```
Options_Data_Table.aoColumns = columns_sort;
```